# How to groupby column names Stored in list through a loop and store there values in new variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have dataframe with  column names as A,B,C,D,e,f,g,h.These columns names are stored in a list as cols1=[A,B,C,D,e,f,g,h]

I have to groupby these columns as df.groupby(['A','B','C','D','e']) and store it in variable names as e

And again as df.groupby(['A','B','C','D','f']) and store it in variable names as f

And again as df.groupby(['A','B','C','D','g']) till the end of the list.

This should be done in a loop.And then store the groupby.sum() values of columns e,f,g etc in a new variable to compare the values of e,f,g,h.

Any way of doing it in pandas.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `sum`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,8,8],
                   'B':[4,6,6],
                   'C':[7,2,2],
                   'D':[1,3,3],
                   'e':[2,3,6],
                   'f':[0,2,4],
                   'g':[7,4,1],
                   'h':[1,4,2]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  e  f  g  h
0  1  4  7  1  2  0  7  1
1  8  6  2  3  3  2  4  4
2  8  6  2  3  6  4  1  2

cols1=['A','B','C','D','e','f','g','h']
cols11 = cols1[:4]
print (cols11)
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
cols12 = cols1[4:]
print (cols12)
['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']

df = df.groupby(cols11)[cols12].sum()
print (df)
         e  f  g  h
A B C D            
1 4 7 1  2  0  7  1
8 6 2 3  9  6  5  6

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   e  f  g  h
0  2  0  7  1
1  9  6  5  6
```